# need a countdown timer script which starts from a particular time and end at particular time and between that time resets every 15 mins

Tags: javascript, refresh, countdowntimer

I have already tried many scripts, but result is not coming as required.

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
//var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $final_date; ?>").getTime();
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $final_date; ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  //var now = new Date().getTime();
  //alert(now);

  var offset = -7;
  var get = new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000).toUTCString().replace( / GMT$/, "" );
  var now = new Date(get).getTime();
  //alert(now);



  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo" 
  if(days == '0'){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "hours "
+ minutes + "minutes " + seconds + "seconds ";
  } else if(hours == '0') {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + "minutes " + seconds + "seconds ";

  } else if(minutes == '0') {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = seconds + "seconds ";

  } else if(seconds == '0') {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours "
    + minutes + "minutes " + seconds + "seconds ";
  }

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "expired";



  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: where is the end date defined? it seems to countdown to now (current time)

Comment: end date is defined in php and in var countdown in javascript. This timer is counting down correctly but when it reaches countdown time, it should count down each 15 minutes until 9 pm